# How can i animate sprites in lua when i press the right arrow?

Tags: lua, 2d, sprite, defold

i'm new to Defold and coding, i have been following a video tutorial from Gamefromscratch to animate sprites which is this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha1Wq2FB7L0&t=5s buto could not make it move when i press the right arrow, it is just stands in idle position.

```
local currentAnimation = 0

function init(self)
    msg.post(".", "acquire_input_focus")
end

function final(self)
    -- Add finalization code here
    -- Remove this function if not needed
end

function update(self, dt)
end

function on_message(self, message_id, message, sender)
    -- Add message-handling code here
    -- Remove this function if not needed
    end

function on_input(self, action_id, action)
if aciton_id == hash("right") and action.pressed == true then
    if self.currentAnimation == 1 then
        msg.post("#sprite", "play_animation", {id = hash("runRight")})
        self.currentAnimation = 0
    else 
        msg.post("#sprite", "play_animation", {id = hash("idle")})
        self.currentAnimation = 1
    end
end
end
```

This is the code, as i said when i press the right arrow it does not move as the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled the word 'action' on the first if statement at function on_input.

This script should work:

```
local currentAnimation = 0

function init(self)
    msg.post(".", "acquire_input_focus")
end

function final(self)
    -- Add finalization code here
    -- Remove this function if not needed
end

function update(self, dt)

end

function on_message(self, message_id, message, sender)
    -- Add message-handling code here
    -- Remove this function if not needed
end

function on_input(self, action_id, action)
  if action_id == hash("right") and action.pressed == true then
    if self.currentAnimation == 1 then
      msg.post("#sprite", "play_animation", {id = hash("runRight")})
      self.currentAnimation = 0
    else 
      msg.post("#sprite", "play_animation", {id = hash("idle")})
      self.currentAnimation = 1
    end

    return true
  end
end
```

Comment: That's "global by default" pitfall of Lua :-(  User doesn't receive warnings about misspelled identifiers.

Comment: We will add a linter to the Defold code editor to warn about these things. And Lua linters exist for Atom, Sublime and others so it really isn't much of a problem.